# Do parent tree hashes in git change when committing?

Tags: git

I performed the first commit and to see what the hash of the tree was I ran the command `git cat-file -P HEAD` which gave me the following output;

```
tree ac9b570150cca9243e1546f6c1b393f851dd7559
author pm 1358978176 +1300
committer pm 1358978176 +1300
```

I then proceed to `add` a new directory followed by a `commit`. I then ran the command `git cat-file -p HEAD` which have me the following output;

```
tree 297f145b042bf11f16ac39fa109df151a8d56ae3
parent dc2683fdf1bf9d5db5f1dc6fbb62576d10d57ae7
author pm 1358985313 +1300
committer pm 1358985313 +1300
```

I would thought that the parent hash was that of the preceding commit i.e. `ac9b570150cca9243e1546f6c1b393f851dd7559`. Have I not understood the use of parent hashes correctly?

Comment: `ac9b570150cca9243e1546f6c1b393f851dd7559` is, according to your information, the hash of the previous *tree*, not the previous *commit*.  You don't show the initial commit id here, but `git log` will show it to you.

Comment: @larsks - Ah that makes sense. If you answer the question, will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ac9b570150cca9243e1546f6c1b393f851dd7559` is, according to your information, the hash of the previous tree, not the previous commit. You don't show the initial commit id here, but `git log` will show it to you.

For example, given:

```
$ git log
commit be2ddc1cdc0cbe0dad791712806b5c155fa357fc
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 23 19:13:27 2013 -0500

    second commit

commit 0e25b7e892bc6e637704909b3d66612807c8edc6
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 23 19:13:03 2013 -0500

    initial commit
```

We can run `git cat-file -p HEAD`:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
tree cdbd58dcba3cf89422f444a310979f6b40dde1ad
parent 0e25b7e892bc6e637704909b3d66612807c8edc6
author Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com> 1358986407 -0500
committer Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com> 1358986407 -0500

second commit
```

In this output, `tree` is the hash of the current tree, and `parent` matches the id of the previous commit.